# How to migrate geth's data

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool, migration

---

### Current situation

There is a `geth` sync service running on a windows 2016 server, in **full** mode.
It provides `--rpc` service, and accept request to create transactions.

For some network reason, it can't send the requests out any more.
When running `eth.pendingTransactions`, it's also not empty.
When running `txpool.status`, it shows there are still over 20 requests in the `queue`.

And, we have prepared a new linux server running the `geth` sync service also in **full** mode.
Now, we want to migrate the service from the old windows machine to new linux machine.

---

### Questions

- I would stop the old geth on windows first, then copy its keys to new machine, this is necessary, right?
- Should I migrate the contents in the `eth.pendingTransactions`'s output? And, if yes, how to migrate it?
- Should I migrate the contents in the `queue` of `txpool.status`'s output? And, if yes, how to migrate it?
- Is there anything else I am missing?

---

*(I asked another question about ethereum on **Stackoverflow** site, if you are interested could you also take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340718/ethereum-which-syncmode-to-use-fast-or-full)*

Comment: Maybe `geth export`?